# What is the difference between $this->renderScript() and $this->Html->script()?

Tags: javascript, cakephp

While I am trying to load script file in my project `renderScript()` is giving me result and `Html->script()` is not. The appearing difference to me in `browser->inspect->sources` is that `renderScript()` is appending version of a script while `Html->script()` is not.

Comment: There is no such function as `renderScript` in `CakePHP`. As far as I know, this function appears in `Zend Framework`. Are you sure you added a correct tag?

Comment: yes. I agree that there is no function like that in CakePHP but still i have seen it used in CakePHP

Comment: Then that's custom code, and you'd ideally show that code. Also you need to explain your problem a little more detailed, "_not giving a result_" could mean pretty much anything.

Comment: Also note that just because you have a function or anything which has the same / a similar name as some library or whatever, that doesn't mean that these two things are in any way related, ie this has nothing to do with the Android RenderScript framework.

Comment: @ndm I get what you are saying. When I searched for renderScript() I got nothing else than android's renderScript. Thus  got confused about any relation of that with web. Please suggest, if you know, what is that renderscript() as it is not related to android's framework.

Comment: As `renderScript` is a custom function, it is not possible to answer your question without seeing the code. If you look for `renderScript` inside `GitHub` you will find many `PHP` projects using this function.  I can only suggest, that in your case it might be some helper with additional logic around `Html->script()`.